# I am unable to set path for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

when using vim .bash_profile I get this

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer 
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi 
fi  
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

".bash_profile" 24L, 771C
```

I want to set path for flutter which should be this line

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/Ahmed/Developer/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: are you on macos catalina? if yes this should help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Du_Esm4EkVc

Comment: No mate I am on high seirra

Comment: so i found this also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbuj1vpvjI8 its for high sierra

Comment: could you please upvote my answer if it worked?

Comment: still doesn't work